# viewDidEnd() method possible in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uibarbuttonitem, viewdidload

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that performs a segue, but I need to invalidate an `NSTimer` when this button is pressed and the segue is performed. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem you can create a touch up inside method with a UIBarButtonItem. This being said, how could I invalidate this timer when this view is exited or this button is tapped? Possibly some `viewDidEnd()` method? Please bear with me, I am new to swift and coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good time to invalidate timers is probably going to be in viewWillDisappear(). You can override it like so in your view controller:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
   // Your code here
}
```